trouble converting a resizing button grid from tkinter into custom tkinter
So, I have been trying to make a grid of buttons that resizes to the window size. I managed to find a solution in Tkinter which I tried and it worked, but as soon as I tried to use the equivalent customtkinter code. It is not working as intended anymore.
The regular Tkinter code I used is as follows:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class mapMaker:
    def __init__(self, master, grid_size = (16, 9)):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.gridsize = grid_size

        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, 0, weight = 1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)
        
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, sticky="news")

        for row_index in range(self.gridsize[1]):
            tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.frame, row_index, weight = 1)
            for col_index in range(self.gridsize[0]):
                tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.frame, col_index, weight = 1)
                btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text= '',
                                bg = "white")
                btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="news")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = mapMaker(root)
    root.mainloop()

import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import ttk

class MapMaker:
    def __init__(self, master, grid_size = (16, 9)):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.gridsize = grid_size 

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky= "news")


        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)


        for row in range(self.gridsize[1]):
            self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight = 1)
            for column in range(self.gridsize[0]):
                self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight = 1)
                btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, text = '',)
                btn.grid(row = row, column = column, sticky = "news")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    app = MapMaker(root)
    root.mainloop()


this is what i got when i run this (Only the green bits are clickable)

It is better to provide a [mre].

As you set text='' in ctk.CTkButton(...) which make the internal label not be created. It messes up the drawing and produce the issue.
Just changing text='' to text=' ' (make the internal label be created) will fix the issue.
